# In Xcode project, Accidently reset all the uncommited changes, can I get it back?

Tags: xcode, git

In My xcode project, Throught sourceTree, I reset all the uncommited changes, is there any way to get it back from git or xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Not probably via git but via xcode , i believe xcode keep local history found a blog https://codeforfun.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/xcode-local-history/ can check if this works.